# Realm Not part of schema with kotlin

Tags: android, realm

FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:    
     student_relam_pojo is not part of the schema for this Realm  at io.realm.internal.modules.CompositeMediator.getMediator(CompositeMediator.java:118) at io.realm.internal.modules.CompositeMediator.getTableName(CompositeMediator.java:71) at io.realm.Realm.getTable(Realm.java:327)
at io.realm.Realm.createObject(Realm.java:1085)at example.com.kotlinexamplebydimple.RealmActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(RealmActivity.kt:24)
```

val realm = Realm.getInstance(this@RealmActivity)

```
    btn_click.setOnClickListener {

        realm.beginTransaction()
        var pojo : student_relam_pojo ?
                pojo = realm.createObject(student_relam_pojo::class.java)
        pojo.nm = edt_name.text.toString()
        pojo.pass = edt_pass.text.toString()
        realm.commitTransaction()
       }
```

Student_realm_pojo

```
public  open class student_relam_pojo() : RealmObject()
{
    public open var nm : String ?= null
    public open  var pass : String ?= null
}
```

Comment: We need to know following things: 1.) Realm version 2.) applied Gradle plugin order 3.) are the RealmObjects in a library module or inside the app

Answer (score 2):

1.) You should use at least Realm 2.3.0 for reliably using KAPT

2.) your plugin order should look like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

3.) if you are using RealmObjects defined in a library module, you need to explicitly specify them in the RealmConfiguration using `@RealmModule`s, see [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/annotations/RealmModule.html).

4.) you might have added this class without providing a migration for it. Consider either providing a migration, or setting `deleteIfMigrationNeeded()`.